# Executing/Running python script on ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, vps

I've uploaded my .html chat file on my Ubuntu VPS, all that remains is to execute/run the python script pywebsock.py which will run the python server. I've uploaded the pywebsock.py to /bin/www and now I want to run it but I have no idea where to start.

When I run the pywebsock.py on my desktop it opens up a terminal saying "waiting connection". 
This is what I've done so far to try and run it:

- Downloaded Putty
- Downloaded WinSCP
- Installed version of Python according to .py (2.7)

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bit unclear.  Your desktop is Windows, and your VPS is Ubuntu.  Presumably, you uploaded `pywebsock.py` using WinSCP.  Putty sounds right, since you want to connect to the VPS by SSH in order to run the script.  Have you connected using Putty?

Comment: Yes, I've successfully connected, I'm thinking that I should use a command to run the pywebsock.py. Also the VPS belongs to a friend but he has given it to me for use.

Comment: Well I don't know about `pywebsock.py`, but once connected I'd do: `cd /bin/www` then `python pywebsock.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a script on the server is the same as running locally.

python script.py

You may check if you have python installed first using `which python` (should return the python location)

If not, get it using `sudo apt-get install python`

after that, go to www directory and run it.